# Is it possible to hide IQueryable from controllers yet still allow for pagination and sorting?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, iqueryable

**Background**

I am working on a web application using a unit of work / repository pattern. I opted to have a service layer which interacts with the repositories. The repositories return *IQueryable* to the service layer and the service layer returns *List* to the controllers.

I decided on not returning *IQueryable* to the controller to make sure that queries would be reused and placed in the proper layer - the service layer. Also because web services may be required later on.

**Question**

What is the best way to allow for pagination and sorting at the controller level without exposing *IQueryable* at the controller level?

One option is to add parameters to all service functions which may return multiple entities but this doesn't seem ideal. Alternatively I could still page on the returned Lists but this would cause a lot of unnecessary data access.

**Edit to clarify**

My repository has a function like:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
{
    return objectSet;
}
```

My service has a function like:

```
public List<Person> GetAllPeople()
{
    return repository.GetAll().ToList()
}
```

I'm happy having the repository returning *IQueryable* to the service as this allows the service to have functions like: GetPersonByName, GetPersonByEmail etc

But i'm looking for an alternative to just giving the *GetAllPeople* function above parameters of 'PageNumber' and 'PageSize'.

Comment: I would pass parameters to page the list at the service layer like PageSize, total etc.. rather than doing it on the controller..

Comment: IEnumerable<T> only allows paging **once** everything has been loaded into memory as I understand it. With a large number of rows this would be problematic.

Comment: An IQueryable<T> type won't be pulled into memory just by returning it through an Enumerable<T> return type. You actually have to do something to trigger the deferred query to execute, like calling ToList().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely most efficient to implement your paging as close to the underlying store as possible.  With that in mind, I believe it is well worth accepting pagination parameters in your service layer methods.

My $0.02:  This is one case where theory should not trump practicality.

Comment: Thanks Riko, I might have to go with pagination parameters for now but i'm expecting that maybe this won't be ideal as my service layer grows.

Comment: @havok - What do you mean "won't be ideal"?  Your talking about 4 extra parameters on each method which take seconds to type out.  Not a big deal. As a rule of thumb you should never allow queries without a max number of results to ever be executed.  This causes problems down the road.

Comment: @jfar 4 extra parameters?! Make a class and use one.

Comment: @jfar - you are correct, and it might not even be as many as 4 but over multiple services with multiple methods I can see it possibly becoming a pain. So I was hoping for a middle ground solution.

Comment: @Ryan - My cutoff is 5-6 parameters. ;)   - @havok - Odd point of view.  I consider what you are concerned about just a normal piece of software development.

Comment: @jfar What I mean is do something like `FindTrades(TradeFilters filters, PagingCriteria paging)`. Then you can use an extension method on your IQueryable to do `.SortToPagedList(paging)` before returning from the service method. Copy-pastsa paging code is just going to lead to an error eventually. 4 parameters are awful easy to get in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, here's one solution:
You can call AsEnumerable() on any IQueryable, and subsequent operations will use the Enumerable (LINQ to Objects) implementation, instead of the Queryable version.

I wrote about many of the details here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ff963710

Comment: Thanks Bill, I like the article. I have edited my question to provide a bit more information, based on your answer i'm not sure where I could slot in AsEnumerable(). Could you please provide a little more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem once before and wrote a blog post about it [here](http://csainty.blogspot.com/2009/12/repository-vs-query.html)

Your situation is not exactly the same, but the concepts and limitations of the Repository pattern are.

Basically what I opted to do was to replace the repository pattern with a query object pattern. The query object held parameters for filtering, sorting and paging, then at the service level was wrapped around the IQueryable.

This way I had a consistent interface between my controller and my service layer that would not need to change if I changed data stores (what if you move away from a LINQ wrapped store in the future?) and controls how much of the IQueryable gets exposed.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper to the `IQueryable` result so you only allow paging and sorting. Something like explained [in this article](http://www.codethinked.com/keep-your-iqueryable-in-check). But I would suggest combining the two interfaces proposed there (`ISortable` and `IPageable`) into only one wrapper.